# documentation of grpc versions compatibility

Tags: python, c++, grpc

Is there a place that lists gRPC versions compatibility?

I can't see anything like that in the [documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/).
I noticed that once in a while new version requires updating the auto generated files, but not always. Since it might differ in languages, I'm interested in python and C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant the compatibility between the library to generate the grpc source code from proto and the library to run it (runtime), gRPC recommend to use the same version (of both code-gen and runtime) all the time.